# Javascript Worker Thread Options?

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I am developing a Single Page Application using Electron (io.js + Chrome).  This application interfaces an SDK that requires polling/heartbeat to run its main/event loop (similar to `libusb` and its `libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed` API).  I was hoping to use a `Worker` thread and a timer but it seems the sandboxing may have made this option impossible--unless I am missing something.  I've tested the timer functionality within the worker thread and it works great.  However, I need to `require` various other modules (ffi, etc) to allow me to communicate with the SDK; however, the `require` is not available to `Worker` threads.

Are there any other options/APIs/modules/etc available that will allow me to start a new thread that can `require` other modules so I can make a simple call to this SDK every so many milliseconds?  As long as I have some IPC to the main thread, this new thread can be the sole communicator to this SDK, therefore there should be no problems with corruption.  Any suggestions or further areas to research would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can use importScripts(), but it will import a whole new instance. You can only communicate with a worker through postMessage()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into this.  Right now I am playing with Node.js `cluester`.  Seems easy, but is failing to create the child process--just dies.

Comment: After looking into `importScripts` a little it seems to suffer from the same limitation.  I need to include `npm` modules like: ffi, etc.  Each of these modules contain their own `require` statements.  So unless I am missing something `importScripts` is not a working option.

Answer (score 1):

After spending more time on the problem I found that Node.js clusters was the best approach for me.  I have the ability to:

- `require` any code.
- Still have a nice neat IPC.
- Can monitor the lifecycle of the forked cluster (process).

One thing I did learn.  I also learned a couple things:

- If you use Electron, as I do, make sure you use the `cluster.setupMaster()` otherwise when the cluster if forked it will attempt to use the Electron environment which will throw a bunch of `bad option` errors and the `cluster.fork` will fail.
- One other problem I found was that if your app does not have a terminal and you use `console.log` within the worker cluster, the cluster will terminate.  I am not sure if this is specific only to Electron (io.js) or what, but this took some time to figure out.  The app runs, and logs just fine with a terminal.  Without the terminal it terminate the worker.  Since my first line of the worker was a `console.log`, it made it harder to find.

There may be better solutions, but this seems to work best for my use case.

For those interested a simplified implementation looks something like this:

**app.js**

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var path = require('path');

var sdkWorker = null;

// MUST use the setupMaster otherwise the default electron 
// environment is used and will fail with:
// ../node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron: bad option: --type=renderer
// ...
cluster.setupMaster({
  exec: path.join(__dirname, "sdk_worker.js"),
  //args: ['--use', 'https'],
  silent: false
});

sdkWorker = cluster.fork({});

cluster.on('fork', function(worker) {
    console.log('WORKER: forked: ' + worker.process.pid);
});

cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
    console.log('WORKER: ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
});

cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {

    var suicide = "";
    if (worker.suicide === true) {
        suicide = " [SUICIDE] ";
    }

    console.log('EXIT: WORKER: '+suicide+ worker.process.pid + ' died with code: ' + code + ', and signal: ' + signal);
    sdkWorker = null;
    //console.log('Starting a new worker');
    //this.sdkWorker = cluster.fork();
});

sdkWorker.on( 'message', function( msg ) {
    console.log("FROM SDK: "+msg.cmdId);
    } );

// Init the lib and SDK platform
sdkWorker.send( {cmdId:"init"} );

// Do an initial enumeration of USB
sdkWorker.send( {cmdId:"enumUsb"} );

// Start the contant polling of the SDK
sdkWorker.send( {cmdId:"startPoll"} );
```

**sdk_worker.js**

```
// Cluster support
process.on('message', function(msg) {
    //console.log("FROM MASTER: "+msg.cmdId); //////// BAD
});
```